# python setup.py install error Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, pocketsphinx

I am trying to run `python setup.py install` for `pocketsphinx` but I am getting error about me not having microsoft visual c++ 14.0 which I have the version 15 the error is as this:

```
C:\Users\fyunu>cd pocketsphinx

C:\Users\fyunu\pocketsphinx>python setup.py install
running install
running build_ext
building 'sphinxbase._sphinxbase' extension
swigging deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i to deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c
C:\Users\fyunu\swig\swig.exe -python -modern -threads -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/win32 -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase_wrap.c deps/sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

The second image which I added is containing the versions of Microsoft Visual C++ I have installed on my computer.
[image: i have up to MSVC 2015-2022]

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text, in particular not error messages. This makes it easier for people to find the question here, using just the message. That said, you did search for the error message yourself, right? In any case, you do not have VS14 installed, just a set of libraries ("redistributables") for use by programs that were built with it.

Comment: ok but what am i missing how do i need to go about it ?

Comment: The `pip` download is old and calls for a version of MSVC that hasn't been readily available for some years. For Windows the easiest solution is to download an unofficial binary from Christoph Gohlke's site.

Comment: @BoarGules please could you drop a link to that and how i could go about it ?

Comment: @BoarGules thank you i have been able to download the .whl file from Christoph Gohlke's site and installed it directly from my folder

Comment: You could also have installed an MSVC compiler, and `pip` would have used that to compile from source. But that is often less than straightforward, especially for Python programmers unfamiliar with the MS development ecosystem. It often happens that packagers omit necessary C header files, presumably because they come as standard on every Linux distro (but not on Windows). Some maintenance teams have even been known to regard the absence of an `.h` file, that *their* code includes, as my fault not theirs. ("Well, why doesn't your system have it?") Which is why downloading binaries is easier.